# Unity - Make two Line Renderers intertwine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, line, renderer

I have two gameobjects in my game that each has a line renderer using the script below:

```
void Update () {

    if(Vector3.Distance(points.Last(), player.position) > pointSpacing)
    {
        SetPoint();
    }

}

void SetPoint()
{
    points.Add(player.position);

    line.positionCount = points.Count;
    line.SetPosition(points.Count - 1, player.position);
}
```

The problem is that when the lines intersect one is always on top of the other like figur 2 in the picture below. I know I can change which one renders on top with sorting layer and order in layer but thats not the problem. The problem is that I want the lines to intertwine like in figur 1. So that when a line cross over an other that one is rendered on top. Can this be done with a line renderer? Or is there something else I can use to get this effect?

[image]

Comment: Ever found a solution or alternative for this?

Answer (score 1):

the `Line Renderer` component stores an array of 3D points and connect them to each other.
If you have a "static" camera (like you are alway seeing the world from above, then you can change the `y` variable of the 3D points where the two lines cross each other.

Let's see an example:
First Line points:
 1. {-1, 0, 1}
 2. {0, 0, 0}
 3. {1, 0, -1}
Second Line points:
 1. {-1, 0, -1}
 2. {0, 0, 0}
 3. {1, 0, 1}

As you can see these two lines cross in the origo. If I change the `y` variable of the first lines second point to 0.00..1 it will be the one that is rendered from camera view.
Kindly let me know if this helps or not.